# Can't create new table in an empty database in intellij idea

Tags: database, sqlite, intellij-idea, datagrip

It seems to be impossible to create a new SQLite data database entirely from scratch in IntelliJ idea or [Datagrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/).

here is what I do:

1. From the database window, create a new SQLite database.
2. The new database shows up in the database window.
3. From the popup menu, you can only create another database.

here is what I tried to do:
[image]

but nothing changes:
[image]

what should I do to be able to create a new table?

Comment: Have you hit the little refresh button to see that the schema changes have taken place?

Comment: I do but nothing change

Comment: I tried to reproduce that behavior, but when I execute an create table statement against an sqlite database file I see the data table immediately in may database tab. Which DataGrid version are you using?  Did you really execute the ddl (sorry for that question)? Did you get an error message?

Comment: Hello, I am Max from JetBrains so I am here to help you. But it's not clear what you are doing. Can you please give more information?

Comment: Thanks, I figure it out, it was a silly mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a silly mistake by me.
it was my first time using datagrip so I wasn't very familiar with it.

when I was trying to create a new database I was just From the database window, create a new SQLite database. and the press OK.
this was creating .sqlite which is used to store SQL code, not a real database.

so the right way to do this is just to click the green + icon and create a new database file.[image]